# How do I include static files from django installed packages?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-apps

Say i'm trying to install Django-datetime-widget.

The installation instructions are

1. pip install django-datetime-widget
2. add django-datetime-widget to INSTALLED_APPS

However, the site is missing the css and js files I see in site-packages/datetimewidget/static, causing the app to malfunction.

Copying the files over manually makes the app work, but is there a proper or correct way of including the static files from the installed package?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just run `./manage.py collectstatic`.